# Change `transform-origin` on a CSSTransitionGroup not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to make a simple component. When a button is pressed, it will show a menu that should slide out from the left. When clicked again, it should slide in from the right. It looks as follows.

I used the following as my `enter`, `enterActive`, `leave`, and `leaveActive` (respectively).

```
.open {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.opened {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.close {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.closed {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
}
```

There is a working codepen [here](http://codepen.io/AlexFrazer/pen/BLqdRG?editors=0110) to show the problem.

What I don't get is: how do I make the close animation start from the right, and move left while closing? It seemed like `transform-origin` was the correct CSS, but it did not work as intended. The initial opening animation was correct, but not the leaving animation.

Comment: I believe the desired behavior can be achieved by setting both transform-origins to 'left'. It opens from the left, and then closes towards the left, like a typical collapsible left nav.

Comment: that helped! I found out that using `all` caused a big part of the problem